# How do I plot a Seaborn FacetGrid with the result of the `groupby`?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following `pandas` `Dataframe`:

```
             A  B              C
0   2017-01-01  1   4.199197e+06
1   2017-01-01  2   8.708300e+06
2   2017-01-01  3   5.401463e+06
```

the result of a groupby operation:

```py
tot_reg = (sales.groupby(['A', 'B'])[['C']]
           .sum()
           .reset_index())
```

I would like an `Seaborn` `sns.Facetgrid` plotting `A` on the x-axis, `C` on the y-axis, for every B there is, I have:

```py
sns.FacetGrid(tot_reg, col='B', col_wrap=4)
```

but although it does count the unique `B` and draws the correct number of subplots, the plots are empty.

How do I plot a Seaborn FacetGrid with the result of the `groupby`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the plot command to facetgrid:

```
fg = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='B', col_wrap=4)
fg.map(sns.scatterplot, 'A','C')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's correct... but why though? Can you elaborate on the logic?

Comment: The logic is you use `FacetGrid` to set up the subplots, then use the plot commands to tell what you want to draw (scatter, line, box, etc). I think it's pretty straightforward and reasonable.